# How to import external css file inside the react component file which is inside the component folder?

Tags: reactjs

I tried giving path the to the file 'import '../App.css';' but I get this error

> ERROR in ./src/components/Card/Card.js 5:0-20

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../App.css' in 'E:\react_projects\comment_cards\src\components\Card'

I think I am giving the path wrong.

Comment: Please place an image of your file tree and any related code if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created your App.css in same folder as your App.js it means that, when importing the file, you have to go back to that path.

Given your apparent path:

> src/components/Card/Card.js

You will have to make the following import:`import classes from '../../App.css'`

Please note that in React we usually use classes as a name of the import.
If you have to give to a component a class, let's name in `.button-content`, you will do it like this :
`<MyButton className={classes.buttonContent> My Button </MyButton>`

Comment: You can install use styled-components and use like
npm i styled-components
and use
import styled from 'styled-components'
// Create a button variable and add CSS
const Button = styled.button`
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color:red;
`
//display the HTML
render(
  <div>
    <Button>Button</Button>
  </div>
);

Answer (score 1):

```
import "./component_name/filename.css"
```

this is the usual way to import css files, but if you are on same folder you can just use

```
import "./filename.css"
```

you can also use inline styles in components like

```
const styles = {
  section: {
    fontSize: "18px",
    color: "#292b2c",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: "0 20px"
  },
  wrapper: {
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: "0 auto",
    marginTop: "50px"
  }
}
```

and implement like below

```
<section style={styles.section}>
  <div style={styles.wrapper}>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

`import "./components/App.css"`

But it depends on from which folder you're importing the module.
For example if you're in component folder and your css file also inside component folder you can use
`import "./App.css"`

but if you are in the src folder and your css module is in component folder you need to import like this `import "./components/App.js"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an External css, Let's name it App.css and you want to import this in your component folder jsx file so simply paste this code:

import '../App.css';